# Configuration form settings

Tags: forms, configuration

I would like to create a settings page for a user which allows them to save the options of a list which is to be used in a custom form. The list is called marketing source and it is added to a form which gets submitted with plain text values to an external API.

I know in field config for select lists you can do this but I want to do it on a custom config page for that specific list.

Foe example I would have a textfield in the config that had values like this

```
1|google
2|magazine
```

Then I need to convert that into a seralised array and store with variable set.

Is there a function that does that already for the field form?

Cheers Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved what I wanted, rather than use key value pairs I just used an empty textfield and used one line for each option and then when retrieving the textfield for the form I used the following.

```
$raw_marketing_options = explode(PHP_EOL, variable_get('marketing_sources_sources'));
```

I then just used the variable directly in the form.

```
$form['Marketing_source__c'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Marketing source',
  '#options' => $raw_marketing_options,
);
```

There may be a safer way to do it as I am not sure how secure variable_set() is when storing plain text but only the administrator will see the textarea anyway.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can use a system_settings_form this is a 'shortcut' creates a form that saves input data via a variable_set(). The tutorial also explains how to create a page for the form.

[Tutorial on settings form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1111260)

variable_set/variable_get always serialize/deserialize any array you pass to them.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question about saving an array for a select list, I already know how to create the form.

Comment: Oh now I get it,

Comment: Oh now I get it. I missread the question. Yes splitting on newline breaks is how I would do it to. 
If I were you I would not split the string every time but save the split version as a variable. Should save on some execution time. 

After exploding you can just sanitize every iteration of the array to be safe. (or even explode every part again but with the '|' item and build an associative array).